# Execute query on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a date field, and I want to execute a certain query when that date reaches the current date. Is there any way to do that on Sql Server?

Comment: AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER.

Comment: A trigger may not be the right thing to do. What exactly are you wanting it to do when a date is hit?

Comment: You can do this with a job that runs in SQL Server Agent, which is the job scheduling software for SQL Server.  Here is the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237(v=sql.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way or say good way is making a Sql - job and second is trigger. But trigger is not suitable and also not advisable to use.

Sqljob is automated process, just give date-time with day and it will executed automatically. In that you call the sp, where first check the date and then process as you want.

First create a job, please check the link

http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-jobs.html

http://forums.asp.net/p/1364020/2826971.aspx

Now create a sp which executed by job like (This is sample example)..

```
create procedure spname()
as
begin
    declare @currentdate datetime = getdate()
    declare @tempdateToCheck datetime = (select datecolumn from tablename where ....give condition if any )

    if(@tempdateToCheck >= @currentdate)
    begin
        --execute statement you want like
        insert tablename .... --insert statement
        update tablename.... --update statement

        declare @tempvariable1 int --anydatatype you define and any no. of variable, you want.

        select @tempvariable1 = columnname from tablename 

        update tablename1 set columname = @tempvariable1 where condition 

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sql server agent job in order to check the date column everyday and if reached then execute query.